# Ocaml parallelize builds

Tags: parallel-processing, ocaml

Let's say I want to build a program that compiles Ocaml source code in parallel. I actually want to understand how to accomplish this with Ocaml today. So given the current state of Ocaml today, how do I parallelize parts of my program?

Should I just spawn new processes with the `Unix` module?
In the case of parallel compilation, does this have any overhead/performance impact?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you want to ask, but you must use fork+exec to run multiple OCaml compiler in parallel, so the short answer is "yes".

Comment: Ocamlbuild runs multiple OCaml compilations in parallel, so it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

To compile files you have to run the ocaml compiler, one for each file. So yes, you have to have to start new processes and the Unix module has the necessary functionality for that.

As for overhead or performance impacts consider this:

1) You need to start one process per file you compile. Weather you do that sequentially or parallel the number of processes started remains the same.

2) Compiling a file takes long compared to the necessary bookkeeping of starting each compile, even if you consider parallel compilations.

So are you worried about the overhead of starting and tracking multiple compiler processes in parallel? Don't be. That's less than 0.1% of your time. On the other hand utilizing 2 cpu cores by running 2 compilers will basically double your speed.

Or are you worried about multiple compilers running in parallel? You need twice the ram and on most modern cpus caches are shared so cache performance will suffer too to some extend. But unless you are working on some embedded system that is absolutely memory starved that won't be a problem. So again the benefit of using multiple cores far outweigh the drawbacks.

Just follow the simple rule for running things parallel: Run one job per CPU core with maybe one extra to smooth out IO waits. More jobs will have them fight for CPU time without benefits.